# Python: How do you intercept a method call to change function parameters?

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is write a wrapper around another module so that I can transform the parameters that are being passed to the methods of the other module. That was fairly confusing, so here is an example:

```
import somemodule

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transforms = {}
        self.transforms["t"] = "test"

    # This next function is the one I want to exist
    # Please understand the lines below will not compile and are not real code
    def __intercept__(self, item, *args, **kwargs):
        if "t" in args:
            args[args.index("t")] = self.transforms["t"]
        return somemodule.item(*args, **kwargs)
```

The goal is to allow users of the wrapper class to make simplified calls to the underlying module without having to rewrite all of the functions in the module. So in this case if `somemodule` had a function called `print_uppercase` then the user could do

```
w = Wrapper()
w.print_uppercase("t")
```

and get the output

```
TEST
```

I believe the answer lies in `__getattr__` but I'm not totally sure how to use it for this application.

Comment: @D.Peter can you put together an example of how this would apply? I believe you, I'm just a bit confused with the mocking documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__getattr__` combined with defining a function on the fly should work:

```
# somemodule

def print_uppercase(x):
    print(x.upper())
```

Now:

```
from functools import wraps

import somemodule

class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.transforms = {}
        self.transforms["t"] = "test"

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        func = getattr(somemodule, attr)
        @wraps(func)
        def _wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            if "t" in args:
                args = list(args)
                args[args.index("t")] = self.transforms["t"]
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return _wrapped


w = Wrapper()
w.print_uppercase('Hello')
w.print_uppercase('t')
```

Output:

```
HELLO
TEST
```

Comment: `*args` doesn't care what kind of sequence `args` is, so there is no need to create a tuple first.

Comment: @chepner Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: @MikeMüller this is what I was just about to hack together. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by calling the intercept method, and entering the desired method to execute, as a parameter for intercept. Then, in the intercept method, you can search for a method with that name and execute it.

Comment: This is doable but quite ugly. It also breaks the way that people are used to using the underlying module.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Wrapper` object doesn't have any mutable state, it'd be easier to implement without a class.  Example `wrapper.py`:

```
def func1(*args, **kwargs):
  # do your transformations
  return somemodule.func1(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then call it like:

```
import wrapper as w
print w.func1('somearg')
```